# Load data from firebase into class models

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to fetch data from realtime firebase database in flutter and I have a problem.

My database looks like this: [Database sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkOis.png)

I am using this as a class model (generated from an online convertor JSON to DART):

```
class Routine {
  late String likes;
  late String dislikes;
  late String title;
  late String numberOfDays;
  late List<Day> days;
  late DatabaseReference _id;

  Routine(
      {required this.likes,
      required this.dislikes,
      required this.title,
      required this.numberOfDays,
      required this.days});

  Routine.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    likes = json['likes'];
    dislikes = json['dislikes'];
    title = json['title'];
    numberOfDays = json['number-of-days'];
    if (json['days'] != null) {
      days = <Day>[];
      json['days'].forEach((v) {
        days.add(Day.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['likes'] = likes;
    data['dislikes'] = dislikes;
    data['title'] = title;
    data['number-of-days'] = numberOfDays;
    if (days.isNotEmpty) {
      data['days'] = days.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }

  void setId(DatabaseReference id) {
    _id = id;
  }
}

class Day {
  late String title;
  late String date;
  late String numberOfExercises;
  late List<Exercise> exercises;

  Day(
      {required this.title,
      required this.date,
      required this.numberOfExercises,
      required this.exercises});

  Day.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    title = json['title'];
    date = json['date'];
    numberOfExercises = json['number-of-exercises'];
    if (json['exercises'] != null) {
      exercises = <Exercise>[];
      json['exercises'].forEach((v) {
        exercises.add(Exercise.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['title'] = title;
    data['date'] = date;
    data['number-of-exercises'] = numberOfExercises;
    if (exercises.isNotEmpty) {
      data['exercises'] = exercises.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Exercise {
  late String title;
  late String sets;
  late String reps;

  Exercise({required this.title, required this.sets, required this.reps});

  Exercise.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    title = json['title'];
    sets = json['sets'];
    reps = json['reps'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['title'] = title;
    data['sets'] = sets;
    data['reps'] = reps;
    return data;
  }
}
```

The problem I am facing is when I'm trying to load the 'routines' into list of objects. What I am trying to do is this:

```
Future<List<Routine>> getAllRoutines() async {
  DataSnapshot dataSnapshot = await databaseReference.child('routines/').once();
  List<Routine> routines = [];
  if (dataSnapshot.value != null) {
    dataSnapshot.value.forEach((key, value) {
      Routine routine = Routine.fromJson(dataSnapshot.value);
      routine.setId(databaseReference.child('routines/' + key));
      routines.add(routine);
    });
  }
  return routines;
}
```

And this is the error I am getting when I try to fetch the data: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZfC3.png)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: have you tried this: change `Routine routine = Routine.fromJson(dataSnapshot.value);` to this `Routine routine = Routine.fromJson(dataSnapshot.value as Map<String, dynamic>);` and see if it works?

Comment: i tried, but it doesn't work :(

Comment: could you try printing datasnapshot.value to see what it looks like before running that line?

Comment: Yes, I printed the value from `dataSnapshot.value.forEach((key, value)` and the output seems to be in a json format-ish: {number-of-days: 1, days: [{date: Monday, exercises: [{reps: 5, sets: 3, title: Flat Barbell Bench Press}, {reps: 5, sets: 3, title: Seated (or Standing) Barbell Shoulder/Overhead Press}], title: Push (Chest/Triceps/Shoulders), number-of-exercises: 2}], dislikes: 2, title: Push Pull Legs Lite, likes: 3}... The problem still the function which needs to convert the values from db to objects

Comment: - You can add a image : you don't need to use imgur
- Consider reducing your code so that the problem is more identifiable and easier to read
- Add an error return by Flutter or explain your problem further

Comment: I don't think that I've added any code which isn't part of the problem. also, I've added the return error at the end of the post. (I don't have enough reputation to post images directly) :))